# MSBuild script dependsOnTargets order of execution

Tags: msbuild

I have this line in my build script

```
<Target Name="Deploy" DependsOnTargets="ServicesInstall;SitesTransfer" >
```

What I want to know is, in this example, what order will the targets get executed.  Also, if ServiceInstall has dependencies do they get executed before or after SiteTransfer.  In other words is the execution done in a depth first or breadth first manner?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an experiment I tried this:

```
<Target Name="Deploy" DependsOnTargets="ServicesInstall;SitesTransfer" />
<Target Name="ServicesInstall" DependsOnTargets="ServicesInstallDependency">
   <Message Text="ServicesInstall" />
</Target>
<Target Name="ServicesInstallDependency">
   <Message Text="ServicesInstallDependency" />
</Target>
<Target Name="SitesTransfer">
   <Message Text="SitesTransfer" />
</Target>
```

and this was the output:

```
...
1>ServicesInstallDependency:
1>  ServicesInstallDependency
1>ServicesInstall:
1>  ServicesInstall
1>SitesTransfer:
1>  SitesTransfer
...
```

However, I suspect the exact sequence is undefined. It is not documented on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx).

In other words, msbuild will only guarantee that the constraints you specify are satisfied. If you need to guarantee `SitesTransfer` and its dependencies are executed before `ServicesInstall`, you should make `ServicesInstall` depend on `SitesTransfer`.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx: "The MSBuild engine executes dependencies in the order in which they appear in the DependsOnTargets attribute, from left to right."

Comment: You can also see a useful execution order at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx, under the 'Target Build Order' heading.